# Mandarin music with clear speech tones

Tags: mandarin, tones

As discussed in [other questions](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/170/can-native-chinese-speakers-distinguish-tones-in-songs), in a lot of Mandarin music the spoken. tones get lost which make it hard to understand or use for learning.

Is there any well-known Mandarin music or music artists where the speech tones are (relatively) well preserved?

Comment: The better way to learn is from videos with lyrics shown.

Comment: 姐就是女王 by 王莎莎: https://lyricstranslate.com/en/ji%C4%9B-ji%C3%B9-sh%C3%AC-n%C7%9A-w%C3%A1ng-i-am-empress.html

Comment: I would recommend the Taiwanese singers "鄧麗君" and "費玉清", both are considered "咬字清晰". Try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvnj_J_dO9s and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjitR7RZEQU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, listen to old songs from the '60s and '70s where good clear diction was the order of the day because the words of a song carrying a moral message mattered more then.

Now it's the thumping music, tailored for dancing and the deliberate slurring of the words to create a "cool" punk rock effect, hence the difficulty in catching all the words, even for native speakers.

Try this relatively modern artist, with easy lyrics of a nice song:-

https://youtu.be/fbWhKaoZXXM?si=UaVSXMNC2P7zbZs4